# REST web service description

Tags: php, web-services, rest

How I can obtain a description of a REST web service using curl??. I have the URL of the service but I don't know what parameters I should bring to service. In SOAP services this description is in UDDI, but in REST I don't know how obtain from PHP.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The REST architecture does not include a specification for describing web services similar to the way SOAP services are described by UDDI. This is because REST is more of a loose architectural style that describes a way to interact with web-based resources rather than a fully specified protocol for web services, like SOAP.

That means that in order to *discover* the parameters needed to be provided with your REST call you will have to rely on documentation provided by the service provider, or trial and error if the service is not documented.

Comment: Probably the best TL;DR for REST I've seen yet.